# Download PDF file and show directly in browser in MVC Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, asp.net-web-api

I am calling a Web API from MVC project. The Web API is returning PDF file that I want to show directly in the browser after clicking on a button. My problem is when I click on the link, it downloads the pdf file and shows the icon at the left bottom corner side and I have to click on it and to open the PDf in acrobat. How I can make it the way that by clicking the link it open the pdf directly in the browser?

This is my code in MVC project that open the pdf:

```
[HttpGet]
public FileResult openPdf(string name)
{
    byte[] pdfByte = DownloadFile();
    return File(pdfByte, "application/pdf", name);
}

internal byte[] DownloadFile()
{
    string serverUrl = "http://localhost/GetPdf?Number=3671"; 
    var client = new System.Net.WebClient();
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
    return client.DownloadData(serverUrl);
}
```

This is the method in my Web API that returns pdf:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetPdfNameByRemRef(string RemoteRefNumber)
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.GetBuffer())
    };

    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Pdf\CreditApplication_08192006_102714AM_et montis.pdf");

    response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = customerInfo.Application_Filename;
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `Content-Disposition` header with value `inline`.

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=fileName.pdf");
```

However, the behavior can differ on different browsers and on file types you are serving. If `Content-Disposition` is set to `inline` the browser will try to open the file within the browser, but it may fail if the file type is unknown (ex. .rar, .zip, .pdf /when pdf reader plugin is missing/, if the browser is old ..  etc.).